# React Native CLI giving error though I removed react-native-cli globally in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I use this command line:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject1
```

And find this error:

```
✖ Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: yarn init -y

Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: -y
```

**Update:**

```
npm uninstall --location=global yarn
```

this line solved my problem. Can anyone explain why this works?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [yarn global documentation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global)

> yarn global is a prefix used for a number of commands like add, bin, list and remove. They behave identically to their normal versions except that they use a global directory to store packages. The global command makes executables available to use on your operating system.

So you could add the install location to your system environment variable like this to use the installed packages:

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

**Or** you can do that with yarn commands like this:

First find installation location

```
yarn global bin
```

Then configure the base location with the following command

```
yarn config set prefix <filepath>
```